# Unable to deploy on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I developed a front end app an I am unable to deploy it on heroku it is saying buildpack not found can anyone help.

this is the url to my repository 
https://github.com/DashingAssassin/OnePush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of cases **Heroku** is used to deploy, run and manage applications written in Ruby, Node.js, Java, Python, Clojure, Scala, Go and PHP.

To push front end applications bitballon provides easiest way.(you can just Drag/Drop  your project files(which should has index files) over there)

```
https://www.bitballoon.com
```

I have used this to host an angular application.(As similar to your git repository which is hacker earth hiring challenge)

[sample angular with bitballon(Front end app)](http://accolitetask.bitballoon.com/)

OR

**USE Heroku**

1. Install Heroku cli in your PC
2. create nodeJS app heroku portal.
3. Create app folder copy all front-end app files into that
   4.place Server ServerJS in beside app folder.
4. heroku login, heroku git:clone -a $APPNAME, git add and git commit.
5. Finally git push heroku master
   --> Server JS :

   ```
     var express = require("express");
   ```

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

```
    var app = express(); 
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    });
    var router = express.Router(); 

    app.use('/', router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

    app.listen(port);
    console.log('---------------------------------- ');
    console.log('Server Started on port: ' + port);
    console.log('---------------------------------- ');
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```